# Table View cell index's stored in an array is losing when scrolling

Tags: xcode, tableview

i'm working on table view for last few days. but, now i'm stuck. actually, what m i doin' is that i i want to store cell indexes into a mutable array. i'd done this part. but, as i scroll the table view, the data stored in the array gets refreshed and the indexes that i stored gets removed from that mutable array. here's the code what i have done so far....

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  if (tableView == table1) {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  ```
  NSString *CellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];

  CellIdentifier = CellId;

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)

  {                
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  }
  NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname1 = [defaults1 objectForKey:@"name1saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname2 = [defaults2 objectForKey:@"name2saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname3 = [defaults3 objectForKey:@"name3saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname4 = [defaults4 objectForKey:@"name4saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname5 = [defaults5 objectForKey:@"name5saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults6 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname6 = [defaults6 objectForKey:@"name6saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults7 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname7 = [defaults7 objectForKey:@"name7saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults8 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname8 = [defaults8 objectForKey:@"name8saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults9 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname9 = [defaults9 objectForKey:@"name9saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults10 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname10 = [defaults10 objectForKey:@"name10saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults11 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname11 = [defaults11 objectForKey:@"name11saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults12 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname12 = [defaults12 objectForKey:@"name12saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults13 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname13 = [defaults13 objectForKey:@"name13saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults14 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname14 = [defaults14 objectForKey:@"name14saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults15 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname15 = [defaults15 objectForKey:@"name15saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults16 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname16 = [defaults16 objectForKey:@"name16saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults17 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname17 = [defaults17 objectForKey:@"name17saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults18 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname18 = [defaults18 objectForKey:@"name18saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults19 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname19 = [defaults19 objectForKey:@"name19saved"];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults20 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *loadname20 = [defaults20 objectForKey:@"name20saved"];

  mTFArrayOfNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];

  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname1] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname2] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname3] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname4] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname5] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname6] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname7] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname8] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname9] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname10] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname11] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname12] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname13] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname14] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname15] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname16] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname17] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname18] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname19] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;
  [mTFArrayOfNames insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", loadname20] atIndex:[mTFArrayOfNames count]] ;

  NSLog(@"%@", mTFArrayOfNames);

  if (indexPath.row == 0) {

      cell.textLabel.text = loadname1;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 1) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname2;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 2) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname3;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 3) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname4;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 4) {

      cell.textLabel.text = loadname5;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 5) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname6;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 6) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname7;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 7) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname8;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 8) {

      cell.textLabel.text = loadname9;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 9) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname10;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 10) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname11;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 11) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname12;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 12) {

      cell.textLabel.text = loadname13;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 13) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname14;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 14) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname15;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 15) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname16;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 16) {

      cell.textLabel.text = loadname17;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 17) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname18;
  }

  if (indexPath.row == 18) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname19;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 19) {
      cell.textLabel.text = loadname20;
  }



  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bauhaus 93" size:18];
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
  [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

  return cell;
  ```

  }
  }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  if (tableView == table1) {
      UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  ```
  if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
      [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

      [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
      selectedCell.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];

  } else {
      [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

      [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

      selectedCell.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];

  }
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];


  names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for (int i = 0; i < mTFArrayOfNames.count; i++)
  {
      if ([self.table1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
      {
          [names addObject:[mTFArrayOfNames objectAtIndex:i]];

    }
      NSLog(@"name1 is  %@", names);
  }
  ```

}
}
Please help me. thankx in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the `names` MutableArray that is getting refreshed ?
If so, it is because you are initializing it everytime a cell is selected. Thus ending up in deleting the previously set value.

- Initialize the `names` array outsite the delegate. maybe in viewDidLoad or where ever you intialize the TableView
- In didSelect, add the new object in the `names` array

Also, it is bad logic to create all the `loadnameX` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add to newly initialized `mTFArrayOfNames`.

- Remove this entire logic from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add it to viewDidLoad or where ever you intialize the TableView

Comment: okay i'll take the names array outside the didSelect method. it will store the indexes the indexes i have selected. but what if user again clicks on that cell and removes the checkmark from it. does the index which the user selects, stored in names array, will remove??????

Comment: i asked my friend about this problem. he told me to take a nsdictionary instead of taking nsuserdefaults. is nsdictionary suitable????

Comment: 1. If the user clicks again to deselect the cell, removeObject from the array. 

2. NSUserDefaults is used when you want to persist the data in the app(Even after quitting and relaunching). I assumed the data was such. If the data is only for the current life of the app, then avoid using NSUserDefaults. Use a NSDictionary

Comment: ok Roshit.... it worked a bit. when i select first index, it get stored in names array and when i select second index, the index stored in the array still stay there and the new index gets also stored. for instance, wt first click on index 0, the index 0 stores into the names array and shows "2012-12-06 12:15:42.533 Splitt[979:f803] name1 is  (
    A
)"

Comment: and when i click on index 1, it shows 2012-12-06 12:16:06.145 Splitt[979:f803] name1 is  (
    A,
    A,
    B
)

Comment: means that the index 0 is still there at index 0 of names array. and when i add second index, the contents gets stored the last index + the new index. that's what i didn't want

Comment: and yes, i want to persist the data even after the app gets quit. that's why i m using nsuserdefaults

Comment: and now we come to the next mistake.. why did you use a for loop to add object. the logic for the for loop clearly says add all object until the current index. Exactly why it added A first and A,B second time.

Comment: yes Roshit!..... it worked.... i removed the for loop and took the names array in viewdidload. and now everything is alright. one last question, if you don't mind dear!... i want to save all the data, but don't know where to save it and how to save it. my friends says "use plist", other says use core data blah blah.... which one you prefer. i want to save the data after quiting the app and fetching it again the next time app start.

Comment: Roshit you said "Also, it is bad logic to create all the loadnameX in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and add to newly initialized mTFArrayOfNames."  how this is a bad logic ???....  what will happen if i use this logic???? does my app will crash???

Comment: 1. NSUserDefaults is used to persist small amount of data. Say username, password, basic user info.
2. Plist are created and saved in Documents Directory / Application Support Dir. This can store medium sized amount of data. Like preferences and basic data structure.
3. CoreData is used when you have to store huge amt of data. Enough data that you need a database to store it.
-- For large data, either Plist or CoreData is used.
-- Unless you need to create a Database scenario, You can always opt for PLists.
-- Also, Plist are easy to implement. CoreData is difficult to learn.

Comment: Coredata is difficult to learn, but once you learn it, you will never want any other method. Cuz its the best and most effective way of data storage. If you have the time and learning curve to know the best, Go ahead and use CoreData. If you want to play safe and get to market ASAP, rig up a quick Plist implementation.

Comment: Well.. I called it bad cuz you have redundant code. You should write the logic inside `CellForRowAtIndexpath`, only if the data to be stored has an effect of the respective cell. Here your data that is stored in the Array is not effected by the row. So then why should    the compiler save the same set of data everytime the row is created. So it is better to move such code out, such that it is done only once.

Comment: okay.. it looks that plist is best for me. at present, i don't have that much enough time to learn core data as you said it is difficult to learn fast. so, plist is good for me bcoz the data i want to store is not little, it's medium sized. can you tell me how to use plist to write and load data???? Plzzzzzzzzz......... thankX in advance. and thankkkkksssssxxxxxxxxxxx for the answers you gave me :-)

Comment: Also, once you create all the LoadNameX properties, use the AddObject method of NSMutableArray instead of InsertObject.
-- then inside `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, instead of checking for each row, use one single line `cell.textLabel.text = [mTFArrayOfNames objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]`
--  Also, now i assume you are hardcoding the `NoOfRowsForSection` value. Instead once you put your `mTFArrayOfNames` outside, you can use `[mTFArrayOfNames] count`. this way your code becomes more dynamic.